# NSFetchedResultsController: ReOrder Sections

Tags: uitableview, core-data, ios7, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm following the example from Apple to setup my sections:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Listings/DateSectionTitles_APLEvent_m.html

My sections currently appear in the following order:

```
Section 0: "Upcoming"
Section 1: "Today"
Section 2: "Past"
```

Code I use in my `NSManagedObject` .m file:

```
#pragma mark - Transient properties

- (NSString *)sectionIdentifier
{
    // Create and cache the section identifier on demand.

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveSectionIdentifier];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    if (!tmp)
    {
        NSDate *dateToCompare = [self getUTCFormateDate:[self startDate]];
        NSLog(@"********Date To Compare****** %@", dateToCompare);

        NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        format.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
        NSString *stringDate = [format stringFromDate:now];
        NSDate *todaysDate = [format dateFromString:stringDate];

        NSInteger differenceInDays =
        [calendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:dateToCompare] -
        [calendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:todaysDate];

        NSString *sectionString;

        if (differenceInDays == 0)
        {
            sectionString = kSectionIDToday;
        }
        else if (differenceInDays < 0)
        {
            sectionString = kSectionIDPast;
        }
        else if (differenceInDays > 0)
        {
            sectionString = kSectionIDUpcoming;
         }

        tmp = sectionString;
        [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:tmp];
    }

    return tmp;
}

-(NSDate *)getUTCFormateDate:(NSDate *)localDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    if (!dateFormatter)
    {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    }
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:localDate];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    return dateFromString;
}

#pragma mark - Time stamp setter

- (void)setStartDate:(NSDate *)newDate
{
    // If the time stamp changes, the section identifier become invalid.
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"startDate"];
    [self setPrimitiveStartDate:newDate];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"startDate"];

    [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:nil];
}


#pragma mark - Key path dependencies

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingSectionIdentifier
{
    // If the value of timeStamp changes, the section identifier may change as well.
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"startDate"];
}
```

In my tableViewController, I setup the NSFetchedResults as following:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if(_fetchedResultsController!=nil)
    {
        return  _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *firstSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startDate"
                                                              ascending:NO];


    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:firstSort,nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                       managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier"
                                                                                  cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return self.fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Question 1:  How do I get the sections to appear in the following order:

```
Section 0: Today
Section 1: Upcoming
Section 2: Past
```

Question 2:  Within each section, how do I sort the rows based on an attribute called `"modified"` in each object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both section and row ordering is 100% dependent upon the sort descriptors.  You want your first sort descriptor to sort everything into the proper section and then your following sort descriptors will sort the rows within the sections.

For example, if you wanted three sections based off of "group" and then you wanted the rows sorted by name inside of the group you would add the sort descriptors as:

```
NSArray *descriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"group" ascending:YES], [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Your section key for your `NSFetchedResultsController` will also need to match your first `NSSortDescriptor`.

Comment: Thank you.  All the objects are sorted based on an attribute called `startDate`.  How would I get `Today`'s section to appear before `Upcoming`.  Do I need to create another transient property called `sortKey` and sort based on that first?

Comment: yes, create a new key to sort on at the top to get everything into the proper sections.  `NSSortDescriptor` instances need non-transient properties so you will need to think about that part of your design...

Comment: I finally decided to change the model and added a `sortKey`.  But now I'm getting another error: `CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) The fetched object at index 3 has an out of order section name '  Past. Objects must be sorted by section name'`  I did a sample project that duplicates the error:  https://github.com/KausiAhmed/FRC

Comment: Your sort needs to begin with your `sectionIdentifier` and then you can sort by anything else.  But the first `NSSortDescriptor` must match the `sectionNameKeyPath`.

Comment: Thank you for taking a peek at the code!  I have been following Apple's code and it has `sectionIdentifier` as a `transient` property and it does not sort based on `sectionNameKeyPath`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Listings/DateSectionTitles_APLEvent_m.html  Should I change it to non-transient property?  I was thinking perhaps doing a separate FRC for each section?

Comment: I did another sample project with 3 FRC's.  The tableView appears like I want it to (`Today` section appears before `Upcoming`); however, its causing an error when adding objects and updating FRCs: https://github.com/KausiAhmed/ThreeFRC   Again, I would love to be able to do this with 1 FRC as in sample project: https://github.com/KausiAhmed/FRC, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: I started another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556123/nsfetchedresultscontroller-multiple-frcs-delegate-error-when-updating  Thanks!