# Using 2 FRCs with one TableView and configuring the FRCDelegate

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I found this post [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556123/nsfetchedresultscontroller-multiple-frcs-delegate-error-when-updating), and I have done my best to convert it from Obj-C to Swift. When I added a new Entity and try to save it to CoreData, the app crashes and highlights this line:

```
modifiedIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: (indexPath?.row)!, section: 0)
```

The error in green behind it is as follows: `Thread 1; EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100008b118)`. I have no idea what this means, and the output panel only shows (llbd) in green as well.

**EDIT** - I figured out that the app is crashing because indexPath?.row is returning nil. I just don't know why it's returning nil.

My VC has 2 sections being set like this:

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

And the title for header being set like this:

```
// set the titles of the tables
func tableView( _ tableView : UITableView,  titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)->String? {

    switch(section) {
    case 0:
        if(positiveFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.count == 0){
            return nil
        }
        else{
             return "Owes you:"
        }
    case 1:
        if(negativeFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.count == 0){
            return nil
        }
        else{
            return "You owe:"
        }

    default :return nil
    }
}
```

Here is how I am creating both of my RFCs

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // load the data

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"statement.@sum.amountOwed >= 0")
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Person.name), ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    positiveFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    do{
     try positiveFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
     }catch let error as NSError{
        print("Fetching error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    let negativFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
    negativFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"statement.@sum.amountOwed < 0")
    let negativeSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Person.name), ascending: true)
    negativFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [negativeSort]
    negativeFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: negativFetchRequest, managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    do{
        try negativeFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print("Fetching error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    positiveFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    negativeFetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    print("\(positiveFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.count) positive fetch count")
    //print("\(positiveFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects![0].statement!.count) positive statements count")
    print("\(negativeFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.count) negative fetch count")
    //print("\(negativeFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects![0].statement!.count) negative statements count")

}
```

Here is the FRC delegate code that I converted from the post above:

```
extension ViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    var modifiedIndexPath = IndexPath()
    var modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath()


    if(controller == positiveFetchedResultsController){
        modifiedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: (indexPath?.row)!, section: 0)
        modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath(row: (newIndexPath?.row)!, section: 0)
    }

    if(controller == negativeFetchedResultsController){
        modifiedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: (indexPath?.row)!, section: 1)
        modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath(row: (newIndexPath?.row)!, section: 1)
    }

    switch type {
    case .insert:
        //tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [modifiedNewIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
    case .delete:
        //tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [modifiedIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
    case .update:
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [modifiedIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
    case .move:
        //tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
        //tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .automatic)

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [modifiedIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [modifiedNewIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)

    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

}

**EDIT**
It seems that the IndexPath.row is return nil for both indexPath and newIndexPath. I tried to prevent this from happening with this code, but I don't know if I'm heading in the right direction with this thought process:

```
        print("\(indexPath?.row) is the index row number")
    print("\(newIndexPath?.row) is the NEW index row number")

    if(controller == self.positiveFetchedResultsController){


        if(indexPath?.row == nil)
        {
           modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        }
        else{
            modifiedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath!.row, section: 0)
            modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath(row: (newIndexPath?.row)!, section: 0)
        }
    }

    if(controller == negativeFetchedResultsController){
        if(indexPath?.row == nil)
        {
            modifiedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
            modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
        }
        else{
            modifiedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath!.row, section: 1)
            modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath(row: (newIndexPath?.row)!, section: 1)
        }

    }
```

And here is how I am trying to save my data:

```
/* STEP 2 - Check to see if that persons names was already used */
    let personFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
    personFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name.text!)

    do{
        let results = try coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(personFetchRequest)
        print("\(results.count)  this is the results count for the predicate")
        guard results.count == 0 else{
            // print("The Same Name is Used")
            warningText = "You already used that name."
            warningMessage()
            return
        }

        /* STEP 3 - Use the name that was typed in */
        print("You can use that name")
        //let personEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: coreDataStack.managedContext)
        let person = Person(entity: Person.entity(), insertInto: coreDataStack.managedContext)
        person.name = name.text

        /* STEP 4 - Save the data */
        coreDataStack.saveContext()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {});

    }catch{
        print("Error")
    }
```

It seems to crash right after the this print statement

```
print("You can use that name")
```

I'm not able to save to CoreData, and I'm not sure why.

**EDIT** This seems to have fixed my issue, I'm still testing but it seems to be working.

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    var modifiedIndexPath = IndexPath()
    var modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath()

    print("\(indexPath?.row) is the index row number")
    print("\(newIndexPath?.row) is the NEW index row number")

    if(controller == self.positiveFetchedResultsController){


        if(indexPath?.row == nil)
        {
            modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath(row: (newIndexPath?.row)!, section: 0)
        }
        else if(newIndexPath?.row == nil){
            modifiedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath!.row, section: 0)
            modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        }
        else{
            modifiedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath!.row, section: 0)
            modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath(row: (newIndexPath?.row)!, section: 0)
        }
    }

    if(controller == negativeFetchedResultsController){
        if(indexPath?.row == nil)
        {
            modifiedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
            modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath(row: (newIndexPath?.row)!, section: 1)
        }
        else if(newIndexPath?.row == nil)
        {
            modifiedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath!.row, section: 1)
            modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
        }
        else{
            modifiedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath!.row, section: 1)
            modifiedNewIndexPath = IndexPath(row: (newIndexPath?.row)!, section: 1)
        }

    }

    print("\(indexPath?.row) is the index row number")
    print("\(newIndexPath?.row) is the NEW index row number")

    switch type {
    case .insert:
        print("\(newIndexPath?.row) is the NEW index row number")
       // tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .automatic)

        tableView.insertRows(at: [modifiedNewIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
    case .delete:
        //tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [modifiedIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
    case .update:
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [modifiedIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
    case .move:
        //tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
        //tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .automatic)

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [modifiedIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [modifiedNewIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Seems like allot of if/else statements for this type of thing. Hoping someone might have a cleaner version of this.

Comment: let person = Person(entity: Person.entity(), insertInto: coreDataStack.managedContext)
        person.name = name.text here is problem

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: did you get data in Person.entity(),

Comment: Yes the data saves.